# App is installed in Emulator but not run from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am working on an application which I am trying to run on 3.x or 4.x versions of android OS. It runs fine on 2.x versions. When i run the application from eclipse i see the following log:

```
[2012-01-10 18:46:20 - myApp] ------------------------------
[2012-01-10 18:46:20 - myApp] Android Launch!
[2012-01-10 18:46:20 - myApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-10 18:46:20 - myApp] Performing com.my.app.activities.SplashScreenActivity activity launch
[2012-01-10 18:48:59 - myApp] Uploading myApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-01-10 18:49:04 - myApp] Installing myApp.apk...
[2012-01-10 18:51:06 - myApp] Failed to install myApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-01-10 18:51:06 - myApp] (null)
[2012-01-10 18:51:06 - myApp] Failed to install myApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device offline (x)
[2012-01-10 18:51:06 - myApp] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device offline (x)
[2012-01-10 18:51:06 - myApp] Launch canceled!
```

And it seems as if app installation is failed. But that's not case. When I check the Application section of the emulator (I mean installed apps), my app's logo is there and it runs absolutely fine from there. What was the problem it didn't run from eclipse? And it was actually installed but showed the message 'installation failed'. As I am unable to run it through eclipse so no more logs available. Please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance...!!!!

Comment: The installation did fail, you must be seeing an old installation on the emulator. Post your manifest.xml for more help.

Comment: same code works with same manifest where minSDKVersion is set to 7 on 2.x versions. Why not on 3.x and 4.x ? I am never able to install it on 3.x and onwards. How can i see previous logs? and it has never failed on 2.x versions.

Comment: Well, if we could see we could tell you. I'll assume something and post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target a newer SDK and support older ones by including something like this in your manifest:

```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

EDIT: Explanation... http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Android version - Codename - API version

> Android 1.5     - Cupcake -   3
>
> Android 1.6     - Donut   - 4
>
> Android 2.1    -  Eclair -    7
>
> Android 2.2   - Froyo -   8    Android 2.3 - Android 2.3.2    Gingerbread - 9
>      Android 2.3.3 - Android 2.3.7   - 10
>
> Android 3.0    - Honeycomb     - 11
>
> Android 3.1 - 12
>
> Android 3.2   - 13
>
> Android 4.0 - Android 4.0.2   Ice Cream Sandwich -    14
>
> Android 4.0.3 -   15

So you can build/compile for API 15 with `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" />`

but also support everything down to Android 1.6 by adding  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />`

Hope that makes a little more sense.

Comment: Well that did the trick...but why i have to give this? Can you please explain? Why it is not necessary in older OS versions?

Comment: @UsamaSarwar updated my answer with some explanation...hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you...so what i get is you build for a specific version and can run on all older versions up to min version specified.